# Apache Solr's bizarre search relevancy rankings

Tags: solr

I'm using Apache Solr for conducting search queries on some of my computer's internal documents (stored in a database). I'm getting really bizarre results for search queries ordered by descending relevancy. For example, I have 5 words in my search query. The most relevant of 4 results, is a document containing only 2 of those words multiple times. The only document containing all the words is dead last. If I change the words around in just the right way, then I see a better ranking order with the right article as the most relevant. How do I go about fixing this? In my view, the document containing all 5 of the words, should rank higher than a document that has only two of those words (stated more frequently).

Comment: could you post the query you are doing and the documents which are coming on top & bottom

Comment: My search query is, "Julian Cribb EPA peak oil". The most relevant document is simply one that mentions Julian 2 times and Cribb 5 times. The term 'Julian Cribb' appears two times in this document. The second contains 'Cribb' twice, 'Julian' once and 'peak oil' once. The third contains 'Julian' once and 'Cribb' once (but not together because of Cribb's which was not highlighted). The last contains EPA 3 times, 'peak oil' once and 'Julian' once and 'Cribb' once. All 4 titles contain 'Cribb'.

Comment: Please add the &wt=xml&debug=true in your request and provide your output of view source in http://pastebin.com/index.php

Comment: I'm not sure how to run this request in solr. I'm using a completely different syntax like index_content:julian cribb EPA peak oil, in the 'q' input field in my localhost/solr/# page on my browser (or running the same string in Solr PHP client's search function in my PHP program). This is my first week using Solr, so please forgive me.

Comment: just add those parameters in Raw Query Parameters of browser where you are seeing the result. This is the problem of term freq

Answer (score 2):

What Solr did is a correct algorithm called [TF-IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf). 
So, in your case, order could be explained by this formula.

One of the possible solutions is to ignore TF-IDF score and count one hit in the document as one, than simply document with 5 matches will get score 5, 4 matches will get 4, etc. Constant Score query could do the trick:

> Constant score queries are created with ^=, which
>   sets the entire clause to the specified score for any documents
>   matching that clause.  This is desirable when you only care about
>   matches for a particular clause and don't want other relevancy factors
>   such as term frequency (the number of times the term appears in the
>   field) or inverse document frequency (a measure across the whole index
>   for how rare a term is in a field).

Possible example of the query:

```
text:Julian^=1 text:Cribb^=1 text:EPA^=1 text:peak^=1 text:oil^=1
```

Another solution which will require some scripting will be something like this, at first you need a query where you will ask everything contains **exactly** 5 elements, e.g. `+Julian +Cribb +EPA +peak +oil`, then you will do the same for combination of 4 elements out of 5, if I'm not mistaken it will require additional 5 queries and back forth, until you check everything till 1 mandatory clause. Then you will have full results, and you only need to [normalise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)) results or just concatenate them, if you decided that 5-matched docs always better than 4-matched docs. Cons of this solution - a lot of queries, need to run them programmatically, some script would help, normalisation isn't obvious. Pros - you will keep both TF-IDF and the idea of matched terms.

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for something that would take into consideration both term frequency as well as how many of the specified query terms are in the results. I'd just like to give significantly more weight to documents that contain more of the search terms than to documents which contain fewer terms (repeated many more times). I'll try your method out though. Thanks.

Comment: it will be almost impossible at least withouth heavy additional programming.

Comment: this might not be correct...if he is using Solr 6 or later, the default scoring method is BM25, not TD-IDF

Comment: i mean, it doesnt matter, both of the scoring will take into account distribution of the terms

Comment: Yes, but repeating terms [affect the score far less](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/10/16/bm25-the-next-generation-of-lucene-relevation/) when using BM25. However, creating a custom similarity might be the best choice to get the results that the original poster is asking for. Another possibility is to hack it using `tf` and `idf` function queries to get a custom score to sort by, but that will probably be (a lot) less efficient than implementing a real similarity class.

Comment: @MatsLindh, yes, you're right proper similarity could be the case, however, i knew, that implementing it could be more difficult, than approach i gave